# Automatically fill sum column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, sumproduct

I have a table of items with its buying and selling rates. Against each transaction, I wanted to show the item qty currently available and the current cost. Here is a screenshot of the table.

[image]

For the columns of Qty and Rate, I have used the formulas as shown below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C$2:C-F$2:F,B$2:B=B2,A$2:A<=A2)
=SUMPRODUCT(I$2:I/J2,B$2:B=B2,A$2:A<=A2)
```

Is it possible to convert SUMPRODUCT formulas as an array formula (returning array) so that it automatically fills whenever a row is added? Something like filling a column using FILTER or QUERY?

Regards,
Pravin Kumar.

Comment: You are probably going to want to explore SUMIF. There isn't much more I can offer without being able to access the actual data (not a screen shot), seeing your desired result (manually entered somewhere). Consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet or a copy of it, or to a sample spreadsheet with enough data added in the correct places to test solutions the problem.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that this is your goal:

- To automatically fill the quantity remaining column with the result of the difference between the two values, if and only if, there are two values provided.

A solution to this objective is:

`=arrayformula(if(and(C2:C<>””, F2:F<>””), C2:C-F2:F, “”))`

This produces a formula that subtracts C from F only if both C and F have values, and for all rows that have values in both C and F. If one of the rows does not have a value, the result will yield “” (blank). This formula should be posted at the top of the column where you want these results to start. In your screenshot example this would be cell J2. NOTE: 0 is still a value, and also that an array formula will not overwrite manually input data, so once you paste that function in J2, you will have to clear the cells below in order for it to auto populate.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I needed. Thanks however. What I want is to sum the (Buy Total - Sold Total) for all the entries on the prescribed date or in past and fill it automatically against the row. And I want this to be done dynamically when a new row is added. What I really want is to make the two formula shown as array formula spanning the whole table indicated by A2:I.

Comment: Your question doesnt make sense. I have replicated your sheet [on two of these tabs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irEVri9opqp5v8MraOdBsvNO6NG8CtjBEgnOC7bufrM/edit?usp=sharing) and still do not understand. Are you trying to make a running inventory total? As in, you buy 50 and sell 40, so you have 10. In the same day you buy another 30 and sell 20. So now the total will be 20. Is that what you are trying to make?